# Can't access context values in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to pass a value from one component within a context consumer to another component as a prop it says it's `undefined`.

```
<ReadingSessionContext.Consumer>
  {(context) => {
    console.dir(context.state.session.duration) // Value is printed here
    return (
      ...
        <Timer duration={context.state.session.duration} />
      ...
    )
  }}
</ReadingSessionContext.Consumer>
```

And the `Timer` component

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    "minutes": this.props.duration.split(":")[1].parseInt(), // Returns error here
    "seconds": this.props.duration.split(":")[2].parseInt()  // Returns error here
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.dir(this.props) // Value is undefined here
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const { seconds, minutes } = this.state;

      if (seconds > 0) {
        this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
          seconds: seconds - 1
        }))
      }

      if (seconds === 0) {
        if (minutes === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.myInterval)
        } else {
          this.setState(({ minutes }) => ({
            minutes: minutes - 1,
            seconds: 59
          }))
        }
      }
    }, 1000)
  }

  render() {
    const { minutes, seconds } = this.state;

    return (
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
        Time Remaining: { minutes }:{ seconds < 10 ? `0${ seconds }` : seconds }
      </Typography>
    )
  }
}
```

I've also tried to refactor this so that the `Timer` component consumes the context, rather than passing it as a prop:

```
function Timer() {
  const context = useContext(ReadingSessionContext);
  const [minutes, setMinutes] = useState(3);
  const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let duration = context.state.session.duration; // Value is accessable here
    console.log(duration); // This logs to the console correctly, and it is a string
    setMinutes(duration.split(":")[1].parseInt()); // Throws error here
    setSeconds(duration.split(":")[2].parseInt()); // Throws error here

    let timerInterval = setInterval(() => {
      if (seconds > 0) {
        setSeconds(seconds - 1);
      }

      if (seconds === 0) {
        if (minutes === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.timerInterval)
        } else {
          setMinutes(minutes - 1);
          setSeconds(59)
        }
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}
```

In each case, the error that gets thrown is - `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

However, in every instance where I inspect the value before calling `.split()` it tells me that the value exists, and is in fact correct, but all of a sudden stops existing as soon as I try to perform some action on the string

Provider.jsx

```
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import ReadingSessionContext from "./Context";

export default class ReadingSessionProvider extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Set the initial state of the `ReadingSessionProvider`
   * @param {*} props 
   */
  state = {
    "translationUrl": process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "translate/",
    "readingSessionUrl": process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "reading-sessions/",
    "session": {},
    "book": {},
    "translations": [],
    "serverPage": 1,
    "clientPage": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "totalResults": 0,
    "sessionId": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Token " +  localStorage.getItem("token"),
    }
  }

  /**
   * After the component mounts, call the `getReadingSession` method
   * and update the state with response
   */
  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await this.getReadingSession();
    this.setState({"session": data.data});
    this.setState({"book": data.data.library_item.book});
    await this.getTranslations()
  }

  /**
   * Call the API and get data for this specific reading session
   */
  async getReadingSession() {
    let result = await axios.get(
      this.state.readingSessionUrl + window.location.href.split('/')[5] + "/",
      {headers: this.state.headers}
    );
    return result;
  }

  makeUrl = sessionId => {
    return `${this.state.translationUrl}?page=${this.state.serverPage}&limit=${this.state.limit}&sessionId=${this.state.session.id}`;
  }

  /**
   * Make the API call to the server to retrieve a list of the translations
   * for the currently logged in user.
   */
  getTranslations = async () => {
    try {
      let url = `${this.state.translationUrl}?page=${this.state.serverPage}&limit=${this.state.limit}&sessionId=${this.state.session.id}`
      let response = await axios.get(url, {headers: this.state.headers});
      await this.setState({"translations": response.data.results});
      await this.setState({"totalResults": response.data.count});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Submit the text that the user has input and get the updated 
   * list of translations from the API
   */
  submitText = async (e, text) => {
    console.log("hello?")
    let data = {
      "text_to_be_translated": text,
      "session": this.state.session.id
    };

    try {
      await axios.post(this.state.translationUrl, data, {headers: this.state.headers});
      let paginationUrl = `${this.state.translationUrl}?page=${this.state.serverPage}&limit=${this.state.limit}&sessionId=${this.state.session.id}`;
      this.getTranslations(paginationUrl);
    } catch (error) {
      console.dir(error);
    }
  }

  setSessionId = sessionId => {
    this.setState({"sessionId": sessionId});
    console.log("called")
  }

  handleChangePage = async (event, newPage) => {
    this.setState({"serverPage": newPage + 1})
    this.setState({"clientPage": newPage})
    let url = await `${this.state.translationUrl}translate/?page=${newPage + 1}&limit=${this.state.limit}&sessionId=${this.state.session.id}`
    console.log(url)
    await this.getTranslations(url);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReadingSessionContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        getTranslations: this.getTranslations,
        submitText: this.submitText,
        handleChangePage: this.handleChangePage,
        setSessionId: this.setSessionId,
        makeUrl: this.makeUrl

      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ReadingSessionContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Context.jsx

```
import React from "react";

const ReadingSessionContext = React.createContext();

export default ReadingSessionContext;
```

Comment: Can you show where you defined the context?

Comment: Updated the question with the context. Thanks

Comment: `console.log` is not accurate ... when logging an object it `'silently fixes'` value when it is updated quickly ... in fact at start there is an empty object and on second render it's fetched object ... render Timer conditionally

Answer (score 1):

Okay. You're really close. You still need to wrap your root component or hierachy with ReadingSessionProvider. So this is how it works generally.

1. You create the context with `const ReadingSessionContext = React.createContext();`
2. You use it to make a context provider. Which you have done when you created the the `ReadingSessionProvider` class.
3. You use the `ReadingSessionProvider` wrap the app section you want to access the consumer. So say

```
<ReadingSessionProvider>
  <App />
</ReadingSessionProvider>
```

4. Now the children of App component can use the values set in the ReadingSessionProvider. Either with `useContext(ReadingSessionContext)` or with `ReadingSessionContext.Consumer`

See this video from Wes Bos for more information: https://youtu.be/XLJN4JfniH4

Comment: `Timer` is already a child of ReadingSessionProvider so it should already have access. As I've mentioned, I'm already trying to use `useContext` in the `Timer` component but it's still returning `undefined`. I'm not quite sure how moving this up a level will resolve this... But I will try next time I have the code open and let you know how it goes :)

Comment: Can you show where you added Timer as child? I don't see it in this snippet

Comment: It's a child of the consumer. It's in the first code snippet in my original post

Comment: No, that's not enough. You need the ContextProvider to wrap the root component or a parent of Timer before Timer can access the state using Context.Consumer

Comment: Just see the outline I gave. You are skipping step 3. Which is very important.

Comment: The structure that I have is `ReadingSessionProvider -> ReadingSessionHeader -> ReadingSessionContext.Consumer -> Timer`. By moving the `ReadingSessionProvider` I'd just be movng it up one extra level, but `Timer` is definitely already a descendent of `ReadingSessionProvider`

Comment: I've tried moving this up a level and the ReadingSessionProvider so that the entire is wrapped in it as you suggested but it's still not working. No matter what level the ReadingSessionProvider is at, you don't seem to be able to pass a value from the consumer into another component as a prop. Guess I'll just have to find another solution. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Hey, if the project isn't private can you sent me a link to the repository? I'll be more than happy to debug it for you.

Comment: No idea if this solved the OP question but in my case, I was wondering why the Context values in my case were not reading, and it was because I forgot to wrap the component with the Provider. Thanks.