# React Component State Not Updating

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm having trouble adding the context to the state of a component that's consuming a provider.

The code below is a child component called `Timer` and the parent is wrapped in the `ReadingSessionProvider`.

I have the `duration` stored as a property of a `session` object that's stored on the state of the parent. And it's stored in a string as `"00:10:00"`, for example. I can access this value in the parent without any issue.

I'd like to split it and store the minutes and hours as individual variables in the state so that I use it as a countdown timer, however, it's seeming impossible to access the values of the context without having some specific event, in this case, the `onClick`.

If I try to set the state before this, the `context.state.session.duration` value is undefined.

In the code below, the countdown timer works with the default values, but when I click on the button, the `startSession` sets the state correctly, but the timer no longer functions. For example, if this duration value is `"00:10:00"` it will remain so.

I've tried various other attempts at this, I even tried asking about passing the value as a prop [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60876019/cant-access-context-values-in-react) but didn't get a solution.

I'm not sure if there's something very wrong with my approach to this, or if what I'm trying to accomplish just isn't possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
class Timer extends React.Component {
  state = {
    'minutes': 3,
    'seconds': 59,
    'timerText': 'Time Remaining: '
  }

  startCountdown() {
    this.myInterval = setInterval(() => {
      const { seconds, minutes } = this.state;

      if (seconds > 0) {
        this.setState(({ seconds }) => ({
          seconds: seconds - 1
        }))
      }

      if (seconds === 0) {
        if (minutes === 0) {
          clearInterval(this.myInterval)
        } else {
          this.setState(({ minutes }) => ({
            minutes: minutes - 1,
            seconds: 59
          }))
        }
      }

    }, 1000);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.context)
    this.startCountdown();
  }

  startSession(duration) {
    this.setState({'minutes': duration.split(":")[1]});
    this.setState({'seconds': duration.split(":")[2]});
    this.startCountdown()
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ReadingSessionContext.Consumer>
        {(context) => {
          return (
            <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
              { this.state.minutes }:{ this.state.seconds < 10 ? `${ this.state.seconds }` : this.state.seconds }
              <Button onClick={() => this.startSession(context.state.session.duration)}>Start Session</Button>
            </Typography>
          )
        }}
      </ReadingSessionContext.Consumer>
    )
  }
}
```

```
export default function ReadingSessionPage() {  

  return (
    <ReadingSessionProvider>
      <Container component="main" maxWidth="lg">
        <NavBar />
        <CssBaseline />
        <Grid container>
          <ReadingSessionHeader />
        </Grid>
      </Container>
    </ReadingSessionProvider>
  )
}

function ReadingSessionHeader() {

  return (
    ...
      <Timer />
    ...
  )
}
```

And the Provider (truncated for readability)

```
export default class ReadingSessionProvider extends React.Component {

  /**
   * Set the initial state of the `ReadingSessionProvider`
   * @param {*} props 
   */
  state = {
    "translationUrl": process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "translate/",
    "readingSessionUrl": process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + "reading-sessions/",
    "session": {},
    "book": {},
    "translations": [],
    "serverPage": 1,
    "clientPage": 0,
    "limit": 10,
    "totalResults": 0,
    "sessionId": 0,
    "headers": {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Token " +  localStorage.getItem("token"),
    }
  }

  /**
   * After the component mounts, call the `getReadingSession` method
   * and update the state with response
   */
  async componentDidMount() {
    let data = await this.getReadingSession();
    this.setState({"session": data.data});
    this.setState({"book": data.data.library_item.book});
    await this.getTranslations()
  }

  ...

  render() {
    return (
      <ReadingSessionContext.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,
        getTranslations: this.getTranslations,
        submitText: this.submitText,
        handleChangePage: this.handleChangePage,
        setSessionId: this.setSessionId,
        makeUrl: this.makeUrl

      }}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ReadingSessionContext.Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: How is the context provider providing the context?

Comment: I've added in the relevant code for the provider. Thanks

Comment: is the context being passed into the consumer? `console.log(context)` before return `<Typography ...`

Answer (score 0):

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState, snapShot) {
If(prevState !== This.state){
this.startCountdown()
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your constructor you need to bind `this.startSession` to `this` if that makes sense.

So you need to have `this.startSession = this.startSession.bind(this);` within your constructor.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {put your state here};
  this.startSession = this.startSession.bind(this);
}
```

What I think is happening is the function isn't bound to `this` so when you say `this.Anything` it's losing scope so your state isn't actually being updated